# Delete S3 bucket with replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are in need of deleting few S3 buckets. We came up with the below steps for deleting the buckets:

1. Revoke the bucket policy used for preventing the bucket deletion
2. Empty the objects S3 bucket
3. Delete the bucket

But few buckets we are going to delete are replication enabled, We need to delete both the source and replication buckets.

But we couldn't find related Infos or blogs for deleting buckets with replication. Do we need to follow any steps like stopping the replication and then delete source and replication buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue:

1. Figure out what is the replication destination
2. Disable replication
3. Remove both source and destination (follow your instruction)